# Minimal polynomial of an element of a splitting field also splits over the splitting field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, my professor used the unproved fact that, if $K$ is the splitting field of some irreducible polynomial $f$ over the field $F$, and if $\alpha\in K$, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ also splits completely over $K$. Why is this true?

Comment: $\alpha \in F$?

Comment: You mean $\alpha\in K$. The standard argument is to look at the orbit of $\alpha$ under the Galois group $G(K/F)$.

Comment: Yeah. Could you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof comes from Serge Lang's Algebra.

[image]

Comment: What is $k^a$? Hi.

Comment: @Nishant: It is an algebraic closure ok $k$, see the second line of theorem $3.3$